# Jquery Datatables + Jquery Tabs = an is undefined error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using datatables inside of the jquery ui tabs. Everything works as expected, except one problem. I would like to trigger a click or select different tab depending on hash value of the url.

This is what I came up with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash == '') hash = 'add';
    hash = hash.replace('#', '');
    $("a[href=#"+hash+"]").click();
});
```

This should do the trick normally but it didn't. `an is undefined` problem is hunting me for the last 7 hours.

I also tried different approach to solve the issue. For example instead of trying to use `.trigger('click')` or `.click()`, I decided to try with jQuery UI Tabs option, select;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash == '') hash = 'add';
    hash = hash.replace('#', '');

    i = 0;
    $('ul#tablinks li a').each(function() {
        href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (href === '#'+hash)  $( ".tabs" ).tabs("option", "selected", 2); 

        i = i + 1;
    });
});
```

No matter what I do it I touch anything on tabs menu, I get `an is undefined for ( var i=0, iLen=an.length ; i<iLen ; i++ ) ...` error.

Did anyone experienced similar problems with the datatables + jquery ui tabs or perhaps you have some advices...

Thank you for your time and concern in advance.

Comment: You're missing a closing apostrophe in the line, after the closing brace: `$('a[href=#'+hash+']).click();`, is that a typo, or is that the same as your live script?

Comment: In your first javascript block `$('a[href=#'+hash+']).click();` is missing a closing quote. And you are using the same quote marks. Try switching the `'` to a `"` for your selector.

Comment: @DavidThomas; I wrote it wrong sorry, it is not the same as my live script.
@ScruffyTheJanitor; Didn't change anything :(

Comment: Wow, that was wierd. I had to use `setTimeout`. Not only `$(document).ready()` because datatable needs time to load, after it loads, there are no problems.

Comment: @Pixeler: you should post that as an answer, since it resolved your question. On the other hand, have you considered using `$(window).load()` in place of `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @DavidThomas; thanks but I don't think it will do the trick because I'm using datatables with server-side processing which means it is actually loading after the page itself loads that's why I need `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I find solution or way around after posting my problem on **SOF**. This question is just like others once again and my 'oh, c'omon now' reaction seems to be in a loop lately.

I'm using datatables with server-side processing. Which means data is loaded after the page itself is loaded. That's why for some reason `$(document).ready();` wasn't providing expected result and I had to add extra time before it will do what I want so;

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash == '') hash = 'add';
    hash = hash.replace('#', '');
    $("a[href=#"+hash+"]").click();
}, 1000);
```

Did the trick.
@David Thomas and @Scruffy The Janitor thank you for your time and concern.